# SQL Server : why is this query so slow?

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

I have a SQL statement to pull records. Certain staff have access to certain records. The staff security is all done in a separate process and tacked to the where clause of the search SQL clause.

Simplified example:

```
select 
    o.id, o.staff.id 
from 
    Orders o
where 
    staffid = 100 
    or orderid in (select orderid from schedule where staffid = 5)
```

vs

```
select 
    o.id, o.staff.id 
from 
    Orders o
where 
    staffid = 100 or orderid in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```

The nested sql `select orderid from schedule where teamid = 5` runs in 1 second. If you paste in the result in its place the main query runs in 2 seconds. If you run the top SQL it takes over a minute to run. For some reason, how do you tell SQL to run the nested select first without breaking it into a temp table?

More info from all your suggestions:

My SQL also has `OFFSET 20 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY`. When removed the query is fast. It can return 1800 records in a 1 sec, but ask for 10 records takes 40 secs.

If I change my order by to `staffid` it runs fast as well. The combination of `order by` and `fetch next` is causing SQL to run a different execution plan. Since the `Where` clause is in a separate part of the software and I can't change the `order by`, it is killing performance.

Comment: `teamid = 5` or `staffid = 5` in the subquery?

Comment: run the query with "actual execution plan" on, and see if it suggests any indexes. also, by simplifying the example and not sharing your schema, you're probably hiding the actual cause of the problem.

Comment: Execution plan shows no index hints. Query cost is split 35/65 which is weird since the time to run is 2 seconds vs 45 seconds.

Comment: Tanner, excellent point, I started removing certain aspects of my SQL to see if it ran faster. Happens that OFFSET 20 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY; is causing it to be slow. If I remove that  both queries are fast.

Answer (score 0):

```
with    scheduleOrders as 
        (select orderid from schedule where staffid = 5)
select  o.id, o.staff.id
from    Orders o
where   o.staffId = 100
union
select  o.id, o.staff.id
from    Orders o join scheduleOrders so on o.orderId = so.orderId
```

Comment: I can't change the main SQL, I have to change the security part of the where clause. The where clause is part of the security session that gets tacked on to many of the report SQLs in our application.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT o.id, o.staffId 
FROM Orders o
WHERE o.staffid = 100 
OR EXISTS ( SELECT 'a'
            FROM schedule s
            WHERE s.staffId = 5
            AND s.orderId = o.orderId
           )
```

Edit...
The join version is faster?

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.*
FROM Orders o JOIN schedule s ON s.orderId = o.orderId
WHERE o.staffid = 100 
OR s.staffId = 5
```

How many rows have your tables?

Comment: over a million records in each.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `Exists`

```
Select o.id, o.staff.id 
from Orders o
Where staffid = 100 or EXISTS (select 1 from schedule s where staffid = 5 and s.orderid=o.orderid)
```

With `In` it is trying to retrieve all of the inner query result whereas with `Exists` it will only check if the row exists

Comment: That's not true for newer versions of SQL. (i.e. SQL2008 optimizer is smart enough to treat the IN as an EXISTS)